# How to create table with a column which accepts float and integer data types?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

For example, I've a table with only 2 columns:

| Table columns | Data type |
| --- | --- |
| Date | Datetime |
| Values | Float32 |

But when I want to insert an integer to the column "Values", script crashes. Yes, I do know that it only accepts the Float32 datatype.

So the question is, which datatype to choose, in order column "Values" accept both Float and Integer Values (if it's possible)?

Comment: could you share error message and how exactly you try to insert data into clickhouse?

Comment: @Slach, client.execute('INSERT INTO table VALUES',[[datetime.datetime.now(),value]]) ; where value =0.
Using ClickHouse driver in python.
But Values column is float datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't get more info from your question.

But I tried Datatype of `Decimal32`, then integer and float can be inserted.

The Sql is:

```
-- create local table and distributed table
create table test_decimal on cluster default (name String, value Decimal32(8), created_at Datetime) ENGINE = MergeTree() order by name;
create table test_decimal_d  on cluster default (name String, value Decimal32(8), created_at Datetime) ENGINE = Distributed('default', 'default', 'test_decimal', xxHash64(name));

-- insert data
INSERT into test_decimal_d values ('name1', 1.0, '2021-12-17 09:46:00');
INSERT into test_decimal_d values ('name2', 2, '2021-12-17 09:46:01');
```

Comment: Thank you!
But I firstly converted to the float value then inserted.
For ex, if value = float(num) and
INSERT INTO table VALUES (value)